# receive shadow whit SpotLight three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I want my objects inherit the shadow of other figures. But I have problems if I put:
objMesh.receiveShadow = true;
I get this error:
http://imgur.com/GWU3qJG

in my code this is what I have more or less.

```
renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
spotlight var = new THREE.SpotLight (0xffffff);
spotLight.position.set (2.4457938219139463,0, 17.37913738929295);
scene.add (Spotlight)

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial ({color: 0x7777ff});
objMesh = new THREE.Mesh (extrude_geometry, material);
objMesh.castShadow = true;
objMesh.receiveShadow = true;
```

if I remove this line:

```
objMesh.receiveShadow = true;
```

my error does not appear.

I can do ?, or what would be the solution?

Comment: ```spotLight``` is not the same as ```SpotLight```, JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Comment: @FalkThiele my translator, changed my syntax. The code works

Comment: can you link a fiddle ? your code syntax still doesn't look good and we will be able to see the console error

Comment: @Atrahasis I made this code as an example. While not work here .. why? http://jsfiddle.net/duzuwgfe/